# How can I convert const char* to string and then back to char*?

Tags: c++, string, char, constants

I'm just starting c++ and am having difficulty understanding `const char*`. I'm trying to convert the input in the method to `string`, and then change the strings to add hyphens where I want and ultimately take that string and convert it back to `char*` to return. So far when I try this it gives me a bus error 10.

```
char* getHyphen(const char* input){
    string vowels [12] = {"A","E","I","O","U","Y","a","e","i","o","u","y"};

    //convert char* to string
    string a;
    int i = 0;
    while(input != '\0'){
        a += input[i];
        input++;
        i++;
    }

    //convert a string to char*

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: If you just need read-only access you can use the `c_str()` function (e.g., `a.c_str()`), it returns a `const char*`.

Comment: when i convert const char* to string i need to be able to modify the string but when i want to convert string to char* its just to return the output. @JamesAdkison

Comment: Simply don't do all these conversions: use `std::string` throughout.

Comment: When using `std::string::c_str`, beware: The returned pointer is invalidated when the `std::string` goes out of scope. So you can *not* use this to return the buffer of a local string.

Comment: `std::string a("jyillit");` where `&a[0]` is `char*` with wite access you're talkin about

Answer (score 20):

A: The `std::string` class has a constructor that takes a `char const*`, so you simply create an instance to do your conversion.

B: Instances of `std::string` have a `c_str()` member function that returns a `char const*` that you can use to convert back to `char const*`.

```
auto my_cstr = "Hello";        // A
std::string s(my_cstr);        // A
// ... modify 's' ...
auto back_to_cstr = s.c_str(); // B
```

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you don't need all of that code to construct a `std::string` from the input. You can just use:

```
string a(input);
```

As far as returning a new `char*`, you can use:

```
return strdup(a.c_str());  // strdup is a non-standard function but it
                           // can be easily implemented if necessary.
```

Make sure to deallocate the returned value.

It will be better to just return a `std::string` so the users of your function don't have to worry about memory allocation/deallocation.

```
std::string getHyphen(const char* input){
```

Comment: i need to return a char* because its for an assignment. how would i deallocate the returned value?

Comment: You'll have to lookup the documentation on `strdup` to see what function they use to allocate memory. If they use `malloc`, you'll have to use `free` on the returned memory. If they use `operator new`, you'll have to use `delete []` on the returned value.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `char*`. Use `std::string`, like all other here are telling you. This will eliminate all such problems.

However, for the sake of completeness and because you want to understand the background, let's analyse what is going on.

---

> ```
> while(input != '\0'){
> ```

You probably mean:

```
while(*input != '\0') {
```

Your code compares the `input` pointer itself to `\0`, i.e. it checks for a null-pointer, which is due to the unfortunate automatic conversion from a `\0` `char`. If you tried to compare with, say, `'x'` or `'a'`, then you would get a compilation error instead of runtime crashes.

You want to *dereference* the pointer via `*input` to get to the `char` pointed to.

> ```
> a += input[i];
> input++;
> i++;
> ```

This will also not work. You increment the `input` pointer, yet with `[i]` you advance even *further*. For example, if `input` has been incremented three times, then `input[3]` will be the 7th character of the original array passed into the function, not the 4th one. This eventually results in undefined behaviour when you leave the bounds of the array. Undefined behaviour can also be the *"bus error 10"* you mention.

Replace with:

```
a += *input;
input++;
i++;
```

(Actually, now that `i` is not used any longer, you can remove it altogether.)

---

And let me repeat it once again: Do not use `char*`. Use `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your function declaration from

```
char* getHyphen(const char* input)
```

to

```
auto hyphenated( string const& input )
    -> string
```

and avoid all the problems of conversion to `char const*` and back.

That said, you can construct a `std::string` from a `char_const*` as follows:

```
string( "Blah" )
```

and you get back a temporary `char const*` by using the `c_str` method.

Do note that the result of `c_str` is only valid as long as the original `string` instance exists and is not modified. For example, applying `c_str` to a local `string` and returning that result, yields Undefined Behavior and is not a good idea. If you absolutely must return a `char*` or `char const*`, allocate an array with `new` and copy the string data over with `strcpy`, like this: `return strcpy( new char[s.length()+1], s.c_str() )`, where the `+1` is to accomodate a terminating zero-byte.

Comment: i need to keep the method the way it is since it is for an assignment. Im just trying to convert the input to string, modify the string and add hyphens to show syllables, and then convert back to char* so i can return it.

Comment: @AryaAtighehchian: I think I addressed your concern with an edit, that happened before the "edit window" on posting expired (so it's not listed as an edit).